# Rust: is `Box<T>` really similar to `&'static T`?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I can understand why this code does not compile:

```rust
use std::{rc::{Rc, Weak}, cell::RefCell};

struct Container {
    list: Vec<Box<usize>>,
    this: Weak<RefCell<Self>>,
}

impl Container {
    fn new() -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        let res = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Self {
            list: vec![],
            this: Weak::new(),
        }));

        {
            let this = Rc::downgrade(&res);
            let mut ref_on_res = res.borrow_mut();

            ref_on_res.this = this;
        }

        res
    }

    fn register(&mut self, v: usize) -> NumRef {
        let i = self.list.len();

        self.list.push(Box::new(v));

        NumRef::new(Weak::clone(&self.this), i)
    }

    fn get(&mut self, index: usize) -> &'static mut usize {
        let elt = &mut self.list[index];

        Box::as_mut(elt)
    }
}

struct NumRef {
    c: Weak<RefCell<Container>>,
    i: usize,
}

impl NumRef {
    fn new(c: Weak<RefCell<Container>>, i: usize) -> Self {
        Self { c, i }
    }

    fn get(&mut self) -> &'static mut usize {
        let c = self.c.upgrade().unwrap();

        c.borrow_mut().get(self.i)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Container::new();
    let mut r = c.borrow_mut().register(1234);

    {
        let v = r.get();

        *v += 1;
    }

    {
        assert_eq!(c.borrow().list[0], Box::new(1235));
    }
}
```

I can understand that `&mut self.list[index]` at line 34 does not outlive than `self.list`.

But at line 26, `Box::as_mut(elt)` should the `'static` lifetime cause `T` lives on the heap with `Box<T>`.

Compiler says that `&mut self.list[index]` should live as long as `Box::as_mut(elt)` and i don't understand why cause `Box::as_mut(elt)` is a reference on the element which is on the heap.

Where am i wrong ?

Comment: Your function returns `&mut usize`, which is not a boxed value. You're also borrowing from `&'a self` to return a `&' static T`, which won't work because the pointers then can't be guaranteed to be valid. Try returning a `Box<usize>`, and try looking into `BorrowMut` for `Vec`.

Comment: Also to answer your question more directly, since the `Box` can be `Drop`ped, you cannot guarantee that your pointer points to the memory you expect (after a drop the memory is deallocated!).

Comment: For example: what happens if `Container` removes and drops the value that you have a mutable reference to? It cannot be guaranteed `'static`, because `Container` is not `'static`.

Comment: `'static` just says: "While *in scope*, my pointed location will not change. I can be *drop*ped, which will invalidate my pointed memory; but I will not *move*."

Comment: @MeetTitan, like a Box which is allocated in the heap, with a pointer located in the heap and which will not change (the pointer will not change).

Comment: No, not like a box. Where the memory is allocated is irrelevant here. I suggest reading about lifetimes. Lifetimes are not how long memory is "lives" for, lifetimes are how long memory "resides" at a certain address; so you can predict and avoid dangling pointers at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `Box<T>` really similar to `&'static T`?

No. The contents of a `Box` don't necessarily live for the life of the program, they only live as long as the `Box` exists, which is often much shorter.

Returning a `&'static T` from a `&mut self` means that the reference returned is always valid, but in this case it is not. It is bound to the life of the `Box` and therefore to the life of `self`.

```
fn get(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut usize { ...
```

or with the lifetimes explicitly annotated:

```
fn get<'a>(&'a mut self, index: usize) -> &'a mut usize { ...
```